# Prolog test whether predicate failed or not

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate which returns a solution from a factbase. When no solution exists the predicate should return "No solutions exists". Returning a solution which exists in factbase is trivial. How to implement "No solution exists" part. I use SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a predicate, say `fact/1` that contains all your facts, you can use an if-then-else statement as follows:

```
fact_or_no_solution(Sol) :-
    (fact(X) ->
        Sol = X
    ;
        Sol = 'No solution exists'
    ).
```